# Use OpenCV to identiy hollow and filled circles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, omr

I'm using OpenCV houghcircles to identify all the circles (both hollow and filled). Follow is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('images/32x32.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)

minDist = 30
param1 = 30
param2 = 50
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 100

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bilateral, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Test input image 1:**
[image]

**Test output image1:**
[image]

> As you can see I'm able identity most of the circles except for few. What am I missing here? I've tried varying the parameters but this is the best i could get.

> Also, if I use even more compact circles the script does not identify any circles whatsoever.

[image]

Comment: Are these images really representative of your application ?

Comment: Yes, they are. These computer generated images will then be sent through an optical set up.

Comment: Weird. If those images are synthetic, you should already known where the circles are.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I have to run the same script on the images produced from the optical set up. (which may not be in the same exact coordinates). Maybe I'm naive here. i'm hoping to get this script working so that I may be able to spot the circles correctly later on from the experiment.

Comment: These images are too easy (simple contouring will do). In fact, many methods will work. But most will fail on the real images.

Comment: I understood your first line but not the second. What do you mean by most will fail on the real images? 

Comment: `HoughCircle` is very sensitive to `param1` and `param2` & can differ image to image, eg if you use `param1=20` and `param2=30` on your first image you will get all the circle but if you use the same values on your second image you wont. Contouring is far more robust.

Comment: @DrBwts Makes more sense.

Comment: Real images are always different from what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative idea is to use find contour method and chek whether the contour is a circle using appox as below.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('32x32.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

inputImageCopy = img.copy()

# Find the circle blobs on the binary mask:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Use a list to store the center and radius of the target circles:
detectedCircles = []

# Look for the outer contours:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a circle:
    (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)

    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    
    if len(approx)>5: # check if the contour is circle
        
        # Compute the center and radius:
        center = (int(x), int(y))
        radius = int(radius)

        # Draw the circles:
        cv2.circle(inputImageCopy, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Store the center and radius:
        detectedCircles.append([center, radius])

cv2.imshow("Circles", inputImageCopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError at: peri = [![cv2.arcLength][1]][1](c, True)

Comment: my bad. I edited it.now

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem.  Using same code as your. No needed to modified. I changed value from 50 to 30. That all.

```
#!/usr/bin/python39
#OpenCV 4.5.5 Raspberry Pi 3/B/4B-w/4/8GB RAM, Bullseye,v11.
#Date: 19th April, 2022

import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('fill_circles.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)

minDist = 30
param1 = 30
param2 = 30
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 100

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bilateral, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('lego.png', img)
# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: you can create a tracker for each of the circle parameters and it will work for circles of different sizes +1

Comment: Thanks Jeru Luke. Fortunately, I was awaiting  for new OpenCV 5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you can always get(or create from real image) such "clean" image, the bounding-box of the grid(2-dimensional array of  circles) region can be easily obtained.

Therefore, you can know the rectangular area of interest (and the angle of rotation of the grid, if rotation is possible).

If you examine the pixels along the axial direction of the rectangle, you can easily find out how many circles are lined up and the diameter of the circle.
Because lines that all pixel are black are gaps between adjacent row(or column).
(Sum up the pixel values along the direction of the axis. Whether it is 0 or not tells you whether the line passes over the grid-cell or not.)

If necessary, you may check that the shape of the contour in each gird-cell is really circular.